# PHP XML fast read

Tags: php, html, xml, api

I load more than 50 XML files on my homepage. An example structure you can see here:

http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?usesystem=30000142&hours=24&typeid=3683&minQ=10000

I need the price "sell" -> "min". So currently I run `foreach()` loops and stop when got it. But my page needs more than 30 seconds to handle this, I think I need a direct entry to the data like:

```
$min = $xml -> children() -> children() -> sell -> min;
```

Can anybody give me the right arithmetik?

Thx step

Comment: Is there any indication as to how often those figures are updated? If every minute then consider caching the finished page every minute and serving that up.

Comment: Those “files” are actually not files, but HTTP resources – and downloading 50 of them just takes a certain amount of time. As @Cups already said, see if you can cache those instead of reading them again every time.

Answer (score 1):

Use `simplexml_load_file` function. Its so simply and quick!

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?usesystem=30000142&hours=24&typeid=3683&minQ=10000');

echo $xml->marketstat->type->sell->min; // 257.99
```

And `SimpleXMLElement` and `file_get_contents`

```
$xml_str = file_get_contents('http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?usesystem=30000142&hours=24&typeid=3683&minQ=10000');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_str);

echo $xml->marketstat->type->sell->min;  // 257.99
```

Comment: +1 Thx thats what i search, but it doesnt make my code faster :(. It also takes 30seconds to load 57 of this files, is it normal??? The 57 data i load the same way like u show, i think its the fastest way or?

Comment: `simplexml` is best one of xml parsers that I know.

Comment: ok thx a lot!!! i save data in sql and update it via cronjobs, so my problem is solved !!

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, i am also working with the eve-central api at the moment.
I have to give you a great tip though, eve-central allows you to pass requests for more than one item.

http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=3683&typeid=3684&typeid=3685&typeid=3686&typeid=3687&typeid=3688&typeid=3689&usesystem=30000142&hours=24&minQ=10000

Like that.

Build a nice for loop that gets all the id's you want and let that construct an url like that.
Once done adding all the &typeid=, add &usesystem=30000142&hours=24&minQ=10000 to it and do the simplexml_load_file(the name of your url here);

Now you can do a foreach on the xml output you get for all the items you wanted all at once.